# What is the general term for concepts like length, area and volume?

Tags: geometry, terminology

In geometry, we have concepts such as length (of a 1-dimensional line), area (of a 2-dimensional square) and volume (of a 3-dimensional cube).

What is the general term for these concepts, such that we could say something like: the (general term) of a 2-dimensional object is area; or, the (general term) of a 3-dimensional object is volume?

Comment: Volume $\phantom{I don't want to make short comments}$

Comment: I have seen the word "content" to refer to this concept.

Comment: Measure?${}{}{}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a list of terms that would work

- Content
- Area
- n-Area
- n-Dimensional Area
- Generalized Area
- Volume
- n-Volume
- n-Dimensional Volume
- Generalized Volume
- Measure
- Lebesgue Measure

Comment: I made this a CW so if you want to add more just edit them in.

Comment: So can I say something like "the 3-dimensional Lebesque measure of a sphere is its volume, and its 2-dimensional Lebesque measure is its surface area?"

Comment: I would say the "Lebesgue measure of *the region bounded by* a sphere is its volume and the Lesbesgue measure of a sphere is its surface area".  Though if it's clear from context (which in this case it is) I wouldn't even write the word Lebesgue.

Comment: Some ancient stock. on Mensuration , (to define and measure basic units of length, area and volume.)  Text-book on Practical, Solid Or Descriptive Geometry, David Allan Low, Vol 2

Answer (score 0):

'[Mensuration](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mensuration)' is the term for measurement of length, area, and volume etc.