# What comes after length, area and volume?

Tags: terminology

> The length of the unit is 1.
>   The area of the unit square is 1.
>   The volume of the unit cube is 1.
>   The $\color{red}{???}$ of the unit tesseract is 1.
>   The $\color{blue}{???}$ of the unit 5-cube is 1.

So this is a fill in the blanks-question, but I've been wondering if there's a common term for this? I'd imagine it'd be "n-volume", but I cannot seem to find any uses of that term, so I'm guessing there is another term?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): ["What is the general term for concepts like length, area and volume?"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1608228/409). I recall looking through old-school geometry texts where "content" was the preferred general term (with "$n$-content" the specific $n$-dimensional term), so it's what I tend to use.

Comment: @Blue I thought there had to be similar question asked about this, but it seem like a more general question than mine.

Comment: I've heard the term תפיסה used to describe the space time occupied by an object: `volume * timeInExistence`. That might translate to "holding" or "capture" in English, but note that one of the dimensions was the time dimension, not another spatial dimension.

Comment: A common theme is called measure theory. In this language length of unit  is the induced Lebesgue measure from the real line and so on.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The term "hypervolume" is in use, but that doesn't tell you the dimension. I don't see any trouble using "$4$-volume" to describe the amount of space the unit tesseract occupies.

Comment: I couldn't find any information on wolframmathworld nor wikipedia, and wiktionary claims it's simply the volume of an n-dimensional object. Is there anywhere I could read about this?

Comment: @FrankVel http://www.benjaminblonder.org/papers/2014_GEB.pdf Does this help?

Comment: A bit more verbose, but "nD hyper-unit" works too. So "4D hyper-volume", "5D hyper-cube", etc. This is generally extensible to any number of dimensions or types of thing you're extrapolating to so many dimensions.

Comment: Four-dimensional hypervolume is sometimes referred to as "bulk"

Comment: Can we just use *volume* if we don't mind about the dimentions?