# Is there a term for the generalization of length/area/volume/etc. elements?

Tags: measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, terminology

A [similar question on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608228/what-is-the-general-term-for-concepts-like-length-area-and-volume) addresses the general word for the measurement itself, e.g. count in zero dimensions, length in one, area in two, volume in three, and $n$-volume/area or - more generally - measure for higher dimensions.

Is there a corresponding term in the mathematical lexicon for the differential element? I haven't seen anything like it in glossaries like [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VolumeElement.html) which seems to only go as high as three dimensions.

Would something like "measure element" be appropriate?

Comment: The volume form might be relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_form

Comment: Is "differential element" not general enough?